# How to load an action in angular directive as a modal

Tags: angularjs, directive

How can i load ActionResult in directive?
i am new in angular and got this bad challenge and i don't know how shuld i do this.
is there any simple way for using modal in angular and load an MVC action in that?!

```
<modal title="Modal" visible="showModal">
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">submit</button>
    </form>
</modal>


ngApp.directive('modal', function () {
debugger;
return {
    template: '<div class="modal fade">' +
       '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
          '<div class="modal-content">' +
          '<div class="modal-header">' +
              '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
            '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' +
         '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
     '</div>',
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: true,
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.title = attrs.title;

        scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function (value) {
            if (value == true)
                $(element).modal('show');
            else
                $(element).modal('hide');
        });

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
            });
        });
        $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
            });
        });
    }
};
```

});

Comment: What's this `ActionResult` you're talking about? You don't mention it anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

In your link function of the directive, make HTTP call to the get the ActionResult. Then place the HTML content received in the ActionResult in the directive using `element.html(HTML content)`

Comment: Thanks for your  answer , but how could i get ActionResult Html using HTTP !?

Comment: Just have to make Ajax call to that particular action method. When you return View() from the action method, it actually returns HTML. So make an Ajax call, receive the HTML and place it inside the element.